Typescript error: one or more specific strings and the spread operator
an api requires a call that looks something like this
WindowCoveringServer.with( <one or more comma separated specific strings> ); 
the permitted strings are held in a string literal enum
export enum Feature {
        Lift = "Lift",
        Tilt = "Tilt",
        PositionAwareLift = "PositionAwareLift",
        AbsolutePosition = "AbsolutePosition",
        PositionAwareTilt = "PositionAwareTilt"
}

whether a device supports one of the features is provided by a config object.  So we could do
if(config.supports.lift) WindowCoveringServer.with("Lift");

but you can see that across five possible items the number of conditionals is significant.  and of course the feature map is of arbitrary length more generally.
I have been using the spread operator to overcome this in javascript.  eg
let withs = [];
if(config.supports.lift) withs.push("Lift");
...
WindowCoveringServer.with(...withs);

and this works fine.
However in typescript Visual Studio Code gives me type errors.
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"Lift" | "Tilt" | "PositionAwareTilt" | "PositionAwareLift" | "AbsolutePosition"'.

I'm only recently starting with typescript so my suspicion is that I have got the type assertion incorrect.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?
the code I am using looks like this
let _withs = ["Lift", "Tilt", "PositionAwareTilt", "PositionAwareLift", "AbsolutePosition"];
let withs :string[] = []
for (const item of _withs) {
  if (Object.hasOwn(config.supports, item) &&  config.supports[item]) withs.push(Feature[item]);
}
WindowCoveringServer.with(...withs);


instead of string[] and .push("Lift"), try using Feature[] and .push(Feature.Lift)

thank you!  I wish I had seen your comment earlier.  You're spot on.

a bit more playing and this seems to have solved the type error.
let withs : Feature[] = []

seems obvious, I'm sure, to anyone experienced!
